# printing previous field in AWK

Tags: awk, busybox

I think awk will be the solution to my problem. My tools are limited b/c I'm using busybox on ESXi 4.0u1. I have a log file from a VM backup program (ghettoVCB). I need to scan this file for the expression

*"Failed to clone disk : There is not enough space on the file system for the selected operation"*

In my file, this is around line '43'. The previous field (in AWK vocab) represents the VM name that I want to `print` to an output text file. In my example the VM name is `TEST12-RH4-AtlassianTest`.

```
awk 'RS=""
/There is not enough space/ { 
print $17
} '
```

`print $17` is hard-coded, and I don't want this. I want to find the field that is one less than the first field on the line returned by the regex above. Any suggestions are appreciated.
[[Awk Input File]](http://felipe1982.com/get/x-misc/input-awk.txt)

Comment: actually, it's previous *record*, not field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update (Optimized version)

```
awk 'NR==1{print $NF}' RS="Failed to clone" input-awk.txt
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $NF}' RS="Failed to clone" input-awk.txt
TEST12-RH4-AtlassianTest
```

---

#### Update 2 (*Uber* optimized version)

Technically, the following would be the *uber* optimized version but it leaves too much chance for false hits on the record separator, although it works for your sample input.

```
awk 'NR<2{print $NF}' RS="Fa" input-awk.txt`
```

---

#### Update 3 (Ultimate mega-kill optimized version)

I wouldn't use this in production code, but it just goes to show you there is always a way to make it simpler. If somebody can beat this for *code golf* purposes, I'd certainly like to see it!

```
awk '!a++,$0=$NF' RS="Fa" input-awk.txt
```

---

#### Original

Assuming your VM name is always the last field in the record you want to print, this works:

```
awk '/not enough space/{split(pre,a);print a[pNF]}{pre=$0;pNF=NF}' input-awk.txt
```

Comment: You can simplify by removing the `if` and moving the match outside a separate set of braces: `awk '/There is not enough space/ {split...} {prev=...}' input`

Comment: @Dennis: thanks, always looking to make things tidier.  Speaking of tidy, I didn't realize you could make RS an actual string until I tried it on a whim.  Pretty snazzy

Comment: @Dennis: Can you think of a way to beat *Update 3* for code golf purposes?

Comment: You can omit the quotes around the record separator: `RS=Fa`, otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

So couldn't you use something like

```
'{if it matches, print foo; foo=$17}'
```